# Display div over other elements

Tags: html, jquery, css

I would like to implement a multiselect with checkboxes as options.

The problem is that the div with options resizes other elements on the same row.

My code is:

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <style>
            .multiselect {
              width: 200px;
            }
            .selectBox {
              position: relative;
            }
            .selectBox select {
              width: 100%;
              font-weight: bold;
            }
            .overSelect {
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              top: 0;
              bottom: 0;
            }
            #checkboxes {
              display: none;
              border: 1px #dadada solid;
            }
            #checkboxes label {
              display: block;
            }
            #checkboxes label:hover {
              background-color: #1e90ff;
            }   
        </style>    
        <script>
            var expanded = false;

            function showCheckboxes() {
              var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
              if (!expanded) {
                checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                expanded = true;
              } else {
                checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                expanded = false;
              }
            }       
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:60px;background:green;width:500px"></div>
        <div id="mainButtonsContainer" style="display:flex">
        
            <button>Button1</button>
            <button>Button2</button>
        
            <div class="multiselect">
                <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                    <select>
                        <option>Select an option</option>
                    </select>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="checkboxes">
                <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
                <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
                <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
            </div>
        </div>
            <button>Button3</button>
            <button>Button4</button> 
        </div>
        <div style="height:60px;background:red;width:500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the result is:
[image]

the expected result is:
[image]

the height of element with id `checkboxes` could be changed (the options could be added dynamically) but it should be display over the div with red background (and others if exists).

How is it possible to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `#checboxes` div from the normal document flow with absolute positioning, and since you'd like it to track the `select` position you need to relate the two by moving the `#checkboxes` inside the `.multiselect` so they can have the same parent.